# How to store txt file (reading/writing) and build for Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, store

I'm making a game about questions shared between people, and I want to add natively some questions to the game. In the way I made this game, I need to store a text file in Unity, that contains on each line information about these questions. I need to read and write on that txt file at runtime.

So I basically made a file `questions.txt` in the `Resources` folder, and it's actually fine in the Unity Editor: I can write and read as I want.

However, when I tried on my android device, the txt file couldn't be found.

I read that it's because the Resources folder isn't built on android.
Then, I'm lost. I've read about TextAsset, but it's read-only. I Couldn't find a way to make this work with `Application.dataPath` and `Application.persistentDataPath`, because the file is actually not created with some script.

That's why I'm asking for some help now. I'm a bit lost and I just want some hints on how to implement that.

Thanks for taking some time to read and help. :)

Comment: Are you importing it through the Unity editor or directly placing it in the folder? Edit : you're right, my bad :)

Comment: Well it is already in the Resources folder before building the apk. I'd like to know if there's a correct way to do what I can actually do while testing with the editor but on android.

Comment: The res/raw and assets folders are reachable at runtime under Android. So put them there. `when I tried on my android device, the txt file couldn't be found.`. That depends on how and where you search. They are there.

Comment: In the mentioned folders the resource file is readonly. So at runtime copy your file to the file system and edit it there.

Comment: @blackapps Well, I don't know if it's the correct path when built on android, but here is my code:
`string path = "Assets/Resources/questions.txt";
        
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);`

and error is 

`DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Assets/Resources/questions.txt".`

Works well in the editor, not in android.

Comment: @blackapps oh yes I suspected I'd have to do something like this, but how do I do that? I mean, I literally have no idea how to get something consistent and easy to use (I use this text file to add questions by simply adding lines to this file, then update the game with that integrated file)

Comment: In Android its a resource. Not a file. So you have to use it differently. You can open an input stream for it and then read and copy to file. How to do that in Unity i dont know. Google and you will find i think. All has been done and asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to, in my case at least.
Made a script that contains a `public TextAsset`. I assigned my `questions.txt` to that TextAsset through the inspector.

TextAsset is read-only. But here is the tip: I completly copied the content of that file to another that I created in `Application.persistentDataPath`, which allows reading **and writing**.

Then, if I want to add native questions the game, all I need to do is copy the lines I need from the TextAsset I can modify before building.

Thanks to @blackapps for the little hint. Solved!